# import objc module to Swift undeclared type

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to use a library written in objc in Swift. My bridging header file is below:

```
#ifndef my_Bridging_Header_h
#define my_Bridging_Header_h

#import "Pomelo.h"


#endif
```

I added the path of the bridging file in build settings already.

The Pomelo.h file is below (you can find the whole library here: https://github.com/NetEase/pomelo-iosclient):

```
//
//  Pomelo.h
//  iOS client for Pomelo
//
//  Created by Johnny on 12-12-11.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 netease pomelo team. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SocketIO.h"

typedef void(^PomeloCallback)(id callback);

@class Pomelo;

@protocol PomeloDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)PomeloDidConnect:(Pomelo *)pomelo;
- (void)PomeloDidDisconnect:(Pomelo *)pomelo withError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)Pomelo:(Pomelo *)pomelo didReceiveMessage:(NSArray *)message;
@end

@interface Pomelo : NSObject <SocketIODelegate>
{
    
    __unsafe_unretained id<PomeloDelegate> _delegate;
    
    NSMutableDictionary *_callbacks;
    NSInteger _reqId;
    SocketIO *socketIO;
}

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<PomeloDelegate>)delegate;
- (void)connectToHost:(NSString *)host onPort:(NSInteger)port;
- (void)connectToHost:(NSString *)host onPort:(NSInteger)port withCallback:(PomeloCallback)callback;
- (void)connectToHost:(NSString *)host onPort:(NSInteger)port withParams:(NSDictionary *)params;
- (void)disconnect;
- (void)disconnectWithCallback:(PomeloCallback)callback;

- (void)requestWithRoute:(NSString *)route andParams:(NSDictionary *)params andCallback:(PomeloCallback)callback;
- (void)notifyWithRoute:(NSString *)route andParams:(NSDictionary *)params;
- (void)onRoute:(NSString *)route withCallback:(PomeloCallback)callback;
- (void)offRoute:(NSString *)route;

@end
```

I write a model Swift file:

```
import Foundation
//import Pomelo


class PomeloModel: NSObject, PomeloDelegate {
    @objc func Pomelo(pomelo: Pomelo!, didReceiveMessage message: [AnyObject]!) {
        
    }
    
    @objc func PomeloDidDisconnect(pomelo: Pomelo!, withError error: NSError!) {
        
    }
    
    @objc func PomeloDidConnect(pomelo: Pomelo!) {
        
    }
    
    func test() {
        let pomelo = Pomelo.init(delegate:self)
    }
}
```

but inside the class, when I compile my project, the error goes:

> Use of undeclared type: 'Pomelo'.

I am actually trying to initialize a Pomelo instance, the original doc of the library says:

```
Pomelo *pomelo = [[Pomelo alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[pomelo connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:3000];
```

but I can't init the Pomelo instance correctly. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Does your bridging header have the right name? i.e. was it the one generated by Xcode?

Comment: yes, my bridging header name is right, I also use it to import a cocopods library which works fine for me

Comment: I created the bridging file myself, it's not generated by Xcode